# (Python) "auto input in cmd"

Tags: python, cmd

i'm trying to make an auto compiler for a file using pyinstaller.
here is the auto compiler code:

```
import os
os.system('pyinstaller Main.py')
os.remove('Main.spec')
```

but then the cmd asks: "The output directory: " C:\ Users... " and all it's contents will be removed! Continue? y/n "
then the user must press y to delete the unwanted file. is there any way to "auto input " the key Y and continue deleting unwanted files?
(The pyinstaller creates the "mainfile".specs, build folder ( unwanted) and dist folder ( program compiled into it))
srry for bad english

Comment: maybe try passing rm -r (or whatever the windows equivalent is) as a shell command.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears pyinstaller has an option `-y` or `--noconfirm` to avoid such an interactive question. Have you tried that?

Comment: thanks mate, it worked :D, :  os.system('pyinstaller Main.py --noconfirm')